# android ListView pass hidden values from one Activity to another

Tags: android, mysql, json, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView created with an ArrayAdapter which gets different values from a MySQL database using JSON parsing. Right now I'm passing some of these values to the next activity when the user clicks on an item from the list:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, ListingDescription.class);

    String place_name = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3)).getText().toString();

    intent.putExtra("place_name",place_name);
    startActivity(intent);
```

That's working fine, but now I want to get 2 more values from the MySQL database which should not be shown in the ListView. Which way should I go? 
I tried adding the values in the ArrayAdapter but then I realized I'm passing the values by getting the textview information. How can I pass in an intent some information from the ArrayList adapter without having it shown in the ListView?
Maybe there's a different way to do this?

This is how I parse the JSON:

```
for (int i=0; i<theJson.length(); i++){
    Places place = new Places();
    JSONObject jRealObject = theJson.getJSONObject(i);

    place.setImage(jRealObject.getString("image"));
    place.setName(jRealObject.getString("name"));
    place.setLocation_address(jRealObject.getString("location_address"));
    place.setOpen_until(jRealObject.getString("open_until"));

    placeslist.add(place);
```

I also thought about just putting the values as Invisible in the layout, but I think that's definitely not the way to go. I'll appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a getter method in Places  as you have setter method already.

List placeslist = new ArrayList<>();

add placeslist to your adapter.

OnItemClick.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String image = adapter.getItem(position).getImage();
    String name= adapter.getItem(position).getName();
 //use these in intents
}
```

EDIT

```
   final CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_list_view, placeslist );
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String image = adapter.getItem(position).getImage();
                String name= adapter.getItem(position).getName();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: In this piece of code, where you put adapter.getItem(position) do you mean parent.getItem? If I pass the two values to the adapter, even if they are not going to be shown in the listview, I can retrieve them with the getItem? Also, position refers to the position of the adapter in the listview or the position of the item inside the array?

Comment: adapter is the custom adapter variable which is passed with the items from your activity to CustomAdapter class.

Comment: position is the item position  that is clicked (passed in onItemCLick)

Comment: Ok, I understand this is very similar to what I'm already doing with all the values I'm passing. The problem I have is that I have 2 values, which will not be shown in the listview, therefore, I don't have them in the adapter right now. So my first question is, can I pass values to the adapter even if I don't show them in the list view? I don't think I can, so when I parse the JSON data should I create a separate list with just the values I won't show on screen but will need to pass to the next activity?

Comment: You can have in your data adapter if you dont need to show on screen as welll just like its position for example.. it is better than having two list values.

Comment: You were correct. I was getting the values from the view instead of the adapter. I've solved this with help from your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Places object through `intent`.

```
intent.putExtra("some_name",adapter.getItem(position).get(position).toString());
```

In another `Activity`:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("some_name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way you can do its using `setTag(Object o)` and `getTag()` method.

Procedure

1. Set the object to the view when you implement the `getView()` method inside adapter.
2. Then `OnItemClicked` call the `getTag()` and manually cast it into the class you defined for your data.
3. Pass the data to your intent before calling `startActivity(Intent i)`